# How to create an installer to install c# application and .NET SDK?

Tags: .net, installation

I have a standard C# application that prints the message "Hello World!" to the console.
I want to create an .msi installer that will install my application and the .NET SDK needed to run the .NET application on the user's computer if it doesn't exist. How can I put it all in one installer and what is the best free program to use for this?